# How to format current time into YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ

Tags: go, datetime-format

Never tried Go before and currently doing a small project. One of the task is to get current system time and represent it in `YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00Z` format. I believe that `Z` means that time is represented in UTC format but when i looked into db, all timestamps are like this i.e., `2011-11-22T15:22:10Z`.

So how can i format like this in Go?

*Update*
I was able to format it using following code

```
t := time.Now()
fmt.Println(t.Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05Z"))
```

Now the question remains, what `Z` signifies here. Should i get UTC Time?

Another question, it looks like that the value i am using to format impacts the output i.e., when i used `2019-01-02T15:04:05Z` the output became `2029-02-02T20:45:11Z`, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go provides very flexible way to parse the time by example. For this, you have to write the "reference" time in the format of your choice. The reference time is `Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006`. In my case, I used this reference time to parse the `Now()`:

```golang
fmt.Println(time.Now().UTC().Format(time.RFC3339))
```

There are also other reference types if you want to see:

```golang
RFC822      = "02 Jan 06 15:04 MST"
RFC822Z     = "02 Jan 06 15:04 -0700" // RFC822 with numeric zone
RFC850      = "Monday, 02-Jan-06 15:04:05 MST"
RFC1123     = "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 MST"
RFC1123Z    = "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700" // RFC1123 with numeric zone
RFC3339     = "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"
RFC3339Nano = "2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999Z07:00"
```

Or you can use you desired reference.

Comment: if we wanted milliseconds, would the format be `2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z`?

Answer (score 2):

"If a time is in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), a "Z" is added directly after the time without a separating space. "Z" is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset. "09:30 UTC" is therefore represented as "09:30Z" or "0930Z". Likewise, "14:45:15 UTC" is written as "14:45:15Z" or "144515Z".[16]"

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone#UTC

```
// Some valid layouts are invalid time values for time.Parse, due to formats
// such as _ for space padding and Z for zone information.
```

and

```
// Replacing the sign in the format with a Z triggers
// the ISO 8601 behavior of printing Z instead of an
// offset for the UTC zone. Thus:
//  Z0700  Z or ±hhmm
//  Z07:00 Z or ±hh:mm
//  Z07    Z or ±hh
```

From the source for package [time/format.go](https://golang.org/src/time/format.go)